# XML namespace reference in XSL stylesheet problem

Tags: xslt

I am trying to extract data out of the following XML fragment:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" ?>
<Stmts xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Statement.xsd" Generation="2011-08-01T12:41:41" >
<StatementDetail AccountStatus="Open" CompanyID="" TransactionCount="182" >
<Transactions>
<Manual.../>
...
</Transactions>
</StatementDetail>
</Stmts>
```

Notice that the  element has a xmlns attribute.

When I try to use the following XSL I get no data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>CabCharge</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Batch</th>
        <th>TransNo</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Stmt/StatementDetail/Transactions/Manual">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Batch"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@TransNo"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BUT! If I remove the XMLNS attribute from the  element, I do get data.

What do I need to specifiy in the XSL to recognise the namespace???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to declare the default namespace of the document in your stylesheet, like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Statement.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Otherwise the XSLT processor will consider the elements referenced in your stylesheet as belonging to default namespace `null`.

Moreover, if you want the namespace exlcuded from the output document, you need to declare null namespace for the root literal element `html`, like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="">
            <!-- your stuff -->
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Do note also that:

- In the `xsl:for-each` you are selecting the wrong element (`Stmt` in place of `Stmts`)
- The attributes `Batch` and `TransNo` do not exist in your input documents.